# Duvida JS com input type file

Tags: php, javascript

Boa Noite, preciso de uma ajuda na parte do input, tenho um 
`<input type="file" id="filesend" name="file" multiple/>`

como faço um script que detecta automaticamente quando o usuário coloca um arquivo no input e envia um `$_POST['file'];` para o `upload.php`?

Comment: Primeiro, adicione `enctype='multipart/form-data'` ao formulário, já que você quer enviar para um arquivo PHP. Pergunta: você quer criar um formuário que não precisa de um `input` do tipo `submit`, é isso? O usuário seleciona o arquivo e o arquivo é automaticamente enviado sem precisar de um clique a mais?

Comment: Já está adicionado

Comment: Sim, quero que o arquivo seja automaticamente enviado sem o input type submit

Comment: Beleza! Adicione onchange="this.form.submit()" ao `input`e pronto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lado, cliente:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit();" id="file"/>  
</form>
```

Do lado servidor use [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php) como @Wallace Maxters propõe.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, não se usa `$_POST` para pegar arquivos. Usa-se `$_FILES`.

Segundo, para fazer o upload assim que você selecionar o arquivo, pode ser feito com jQuery.

Desenvolvi um plugin para poder fazer isso de maneira mais fácil.

Veja:

https://gist.github.com/wallacemaxters/7f29b8c8702d06a2afdf

De forma bem simples, pode ser feito assim:

```
$('#filesend').change(function () {

    if (!$(this).val()) return alert('Selecione um arquivo');

     $(this).ajaxUpload({url: 'testando'});
});
```

Comment: Do lado servidor, sim. Do lado cliente, no formulário, o atributo `method` é `POST`.

Comment: Não entendi o que você quis dizer. A variável `$_POST` que está na sua pergunta não vai pegar o arquivo. Somente a variável `$_FILES`. Não existe essas variáveis no lado do cliente.

Comment: Entendo! É que quando ele diz "input e envia um $_POST['file'];", eu entendo que ele quer dizer "submeter o formulário".

Comment: Obrigado, os dois métodos funcionam, porém optei pelo do Eduardo pois é mais simples e a aplicação está bem grande